# Looping over list of df and returning df in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have a list of dataframes, and for each, I wanted to multiply specific columns by a factor of 10. I typically use python, and am having trouble accomplishing this in R. In python it would be something to the effect of this:

```
files.list = list(zt2, zt6, zt10, zt14, zt18, zt22)

for (f in files): 
   for (i in 3:ncol(f)){ 
       f[i] = f[i]*10
   }
}
```

however, in R, this is simply creating a df 'f' and storing the values of my last iterated df in it. What is the proper way of doing this in R?

Comment: Python pandas does not have `ncol()`. And in pandas, use apply inside loop: `colrng = list(range(3, len(df.columns))); f[colrng] = f[colrng].apply(lambda col: col * 10, axis=1)`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a double loop, one is enough:

```
a <- data.frame(a=1:10,b=2:11,c=3:12)
b <- a*2
c <- a^2

files.list <- list(a,b,c)

for(i in 1:length(files.list)){
  files.list[[i]] <- files.list[[i]]*10
}
```

Check a df's head:

```
head(files.list[[1]])

   a  b  c
1 10 20 30
2 20 30 40
3 30 40 50
4 40 50 60
5 50 60 70
6 60 70 80
```

Comment: Not all columns are multiplied by 10, only columns from 3 to last. In this case do `files.list[[i]][,3:ncol(files.list[[i]])] <- files.list[[i]][,3:ncol(files.list[[i]])]*10`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have potentially variable number of columns and want to multiple 3rd column through last column by 10. I would use `lapply`:

```
# Sample data:
files.list = list(mtcars, data.frame(x = letters, y = runif(26), z = rnorm(26)))

files.list = lapply(files.list, function(d) {
    d[3:ncol(d)] = d[3:ncol(d)] * 10
    return(d)
})
```

This is equivalent to a for loop:

```
for (i in seq_along(files.list)) {
    d = files.list[[i]]
    d[3:ncol(d)] = d[3:ncol(d)] * 10
    files.list[[i]] = d
}
```

---

You could also write the for loop to modify the data frames in place, but this involves a lot of brackets:

```
for (i in seq_along(files.list)) {
    files.list[[i]][3:ncol(files.list[[i]])] = files.list[[i]][3:ncol(files.list[[i]])] * 10
}
```

Though it can be improved if we use `df[-(1:2)]` to omit the first two columns rather than `df[3:ncol(df)]` to select the third through nth:

```
for (i in seq_along(files.list)) {
    files.list[[i]][-(1:2)] = files.list[[i]][-(1:2)] * 10
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution using `lapply` and the example data from @aldo_tapia:

```
a <- data.frame(a=1:10,b=2:11,c=3:12)
b <- a*2
c <- a^2

files.list <- list(a,b,c)

lapply(files.list,  function(x) x[,3:ncol(x)] * 10)
```

Comment: @Parfait well yea of course it only returns one column if he wants to subset column three onward and the test data set has three columns.

Comment: Sorry my mistaken terminology, OP wants to only change column 3 onward but keep entire df.